не применяются стили к ejs странице ошибка в консоле:
в консоле браузера
sign_in:1 Refused to apply style from 'http://localhost:3000/desing/sign_in.css' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled.

в разделе Network
Request URL:
http://localhost:3000/desing/sign_in.css
Request Method:
GET
Status Code:
404 Not Found
Referrer Policy:
strict-origin-when-cross-origin
Расположение файлов:
Network>
    public>
        desing>
            sign_in.css
    site>
        server>
           server.js
           str>
             sign_in.ejs

код server.js


const ejs = require("ejs")

const express = require('express')
const session = require('express-session')

const bc = require('bcrypt')

const app = express()

const sql = require('sqlite3')

const crypto = require('crypto')

const parser = require('body-parser');
const path = require("path")
const { log } = require("console")

app.use(express.static('public', {extensions: ['css'],
    setHeaders: (res, path) => {
        if (path.endsWith('.css')){
            res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/css');
        }
    }
}));

const db = new sql.Database('./auth/auth.qlite3', (err)=>{
    if (err){
        console.log('Errpor' + err)
    }else{
        console.log('Databes Connected!')
        return;
    }
    }
    )
    db.run(`CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS users (
        id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
        login TEXT UNIQUE NOT NULL,
        password TEXT NOT NULL)`)

app.use(parser.urlencoded({extended: false}))
app.use(parser.json())
//register
app.post('/sign_up', (req, res)=>{
    let login_u = req.body.login_u;
    let password_u = req.body.password_u;
    
    bc.genSalt(10, (err, salt) => {
        if (err){
            console.log('Ошибка:' + err)
            return;
        }
        bc.hash(password_u, salt, (err, hash) => {
            if (err){
                console.log('Ошибка при Hash' + err.message)
                return;
            }
            
            db.get(`SELECT * FROM users WHERE login=?`, [login_u],(err, row)=>{
            if (err){
                console.log('Error:' + err)
                res.status(500).json({error:'Ошибка при получении данных!'})
                return;
            }
            if(row){
                res.status(400).json({error:`Пользователь с логином ${login_u} - уже существует!`})
                console.log(`Пользователь с логином ${login_u} - уже существует!`)
            }
        })
        
                db.run(`INSERT INTO users (login, password) VALUES (?, ?)`, [login_u, hash],
                    (err)=> {
                        if (err){
                            console.log('Ошибка:' + err)
                            res.status(500, 'Ошибка при добавлении пользователя')
                            return;
                        }
                        res.send(`User ${login_u} is add`)
                    }
                )
            })
        })
        
    
        })

app.use(session({
    secret: crypto.randomBytes(32).toString('hex'),
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: false,
    cookie:{maxAge: 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24}
}))

app.post('/sign_in', (req, res) => {
    const login = req.body.login;
    const password = req.body.password;

    console.log(login)
    console.log(password)

    db.get(`SELECT * FROM users WHERE login = ?`, [login], (err, row) => {
        if (err) {
            console.error(err);
            res.status(500).send('Ошибка при получении данных');
            return;
        }

        if (row) {
            // Сравниваем пароли
            bc.compare(password, row.password, (err, match) => {
                if (err) {
                    console.log('Ошибка при проверке пароля:', err);
                    res.status(500).send('Ошибка при проверке пароля');
                    return;
                }

                // Проверяем результат сравнения 
                if (match) {
                    req.session.loggedIn = true;
                    req.session.userId = row.id;
                    req.session.username = row.login;
                    res.status(200).send('Авторизация прошла успешно!');
                } else {
                    res.status(400).send('Неверный пароль!');
                }
            }); 
        } else {
            res.status(404).send('Пользователь не найден');
        }
    });
});



app.get('/profile', (req, res)=>{
    if (req.session.loggedIn) {
        res.send('Авторизован!')
        console.log('+')
    }else{
        res.redirect('/sign_in')
    }
})


app.set('view engine', 'ejs')
app.set('views', __dirname)
app.get('/sign_up', (req, res) => {
    res.render('./str/sign_up.ejs')
})

app.get('/logout', (req, res)=>{
    req.session.destroy((err) =>{
        if (err){
            console.error('Ошибка при уничтожении сессии' + err);
            res.status(500).send('Ошибка при уничтожении сессии')
            return;   
        }
        res.redirect('/sign_in')
    })
})

app.get('/sign_in', (req, res) => {
    res.render('./str/sign_in.ejs')
    })

app.listen(3000, ()=>{
    console.log('Сервер работает!')
})



код sign_in.ejs


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Sign in</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/desing/sign_in.css">
</head>
<body>
   <header>
        <div class="txt1_net">Network</div>
        <div class="txt2_net">Welcome to Network</div>
        <div class="txt3_sign_up">создать акаунт</div>
   </header>
   <header>
        <input class="int1_log" id="int1_log" type="text" placeholder="Login" min="3">
        <input class="int2_pass" type="password" placeholder="password" min="5">
   </header>
   <header>
        <a class="lnk1_pass">Забыл пароль?</a>
        <a class="lnk2_sign_up">sign up</a>
        <button class="btn1_sign_in" id="btn1_sign_in">sign in</button>
   </header>
   <script>
    document.querySelector('.btn1_sign_in').addEventListener('click', function(){
        let login = document.querySelector('.int1_log').value;
        let password = document.querySelector('.int2_pass').value;

        login = encodeURIComponent(login)
        password = encodeURIComponent(password)

        fetch('/sign_in', {
            method : 'POST',
            headers : {
                'Content-Type':'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
            },
            body : new URLSearchParams({login, password}).toString()
        }) // Добавлены скобки после body
        .then(response => {
            if (response.ok){
                console.log(`Проверка...`)
            }else {
                response.text().then(text =>{
                    console.error(`Ошибка при проверке:${text}`);
                    throw new Error(text);
                })

            }
        })
        .catch(error =>{
            console.log('Ошибка при отправке запроса:', error)
            console.status(500, error)    
        });
    });
</script>

</body>
</html>



